# Splice is not working in javascript. Why am I getting an error?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to have unique images populate everytime a user presses a button. The splice option is being used here but in the console I am receiving an error that arrayCopy.splice is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getRandomImg() {

  let arrayCopy = "imgArray";
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayCopy.length);
    let splicedItem = arrayCopy.splice(randNum, 1)[0];
    newArray.push(splicedItem);
  }
  return newArray;
};

getRandomImg(imgVariable["imgArray"]);
```

I tried googling to see if there were similar issues occurring and could not find a solution.
Im a junior developer really needing the help! Thank you.

Comment: `arrayCopy` is a string, not an array. You can't splice a string.

Comment: You're passing an argument to `getRandomImg()`, but it doesn't have a parameter variable.

Comment: Is `imgArray` supposed to be the function parameter?

Answer (score 1):

you are using an arrayCopy which is string.
this is a fixed code.

```
console.log(getRandomImg(["imgArray1","imgArray2","imgArray3"]))
function getRandomImg(arrayCopy) {
//   let arrayCopy = "imgArray";
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayCopy.length);
    let splicedItem = arrayCopy.splice(randNum, 1)[0];
    newArray.push(splicedItem);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```